# How to query and compare remote, not linked, databases in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got 2 remote access databases which I can query from another access database in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM   (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\A.accdb')
SELECT * FROM   (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\A.accdb')
```

**TABLE A**

| ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jesse Pinkman |
| 2 | Skyler White |
| 3 | Henk Schrader |

**TABLE B**

| ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jesse Pinkman |
| 2 | Skyler White |
| 3 | Henk Schrader |
| 4 | Saul Goodman |

I am trying to compare both tables in the following way, but it doesn't return anything

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\A.accdb') x 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\B.accdb') y 
ON (x.[ID] = y.[ID]) 
WHERE ((y.ID) Is Null)
```

My question is, how do I compare two remote access databases.
The desired outcome of above example would be:

| ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Saul Goodman |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the difference in both files you have do this:

```
SELECT 'New in A file', X.*
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\A.accdb') x 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\B.accdb') y 
ON (x.[ID] = y.[ID]) 
WHERE ((y.ID) Is Null)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'New in B file', X.*
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\B.accdb') x 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM DGConcept IN 'C:\Users\Gusto\Desktop\A.accdb') y 
ON (x.[ID] = y.[ID]) 
WHERE ((y.ID) Is Null)
```

Comment: your solution gives a `syntax error in FROM clause`

Comment: try it with the ( ) .  You are doing this in MS Access?

Comment: I am doing this in Access, Your update now gives a `syntax error in JOIN operation` (highlighting the `IN`)

Comment: yes I looked at the docs -- looks like alias like this are not supported

Comment: looks like your original code is correct -- what was the problem you were having with it?

Comment: It does not return the differences between the 2 tables (results are empty, although there is a new record)

Comment: is the new item in X or Y?

Comment: In the example I described, the new item is in Table B = x

Comment: I just saw your updated answer, This one works

Answer (score 0):

Likely you'll need to create a link to the other table using VBA and the ADODB library if you're using Access.

[MS Access Link Table With VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899011/ms-access-link-table-with-vba)